# Golang. Почему меняется значение в карте?

Tags: golang

Не могу понять почему при присвоении элемента карты переменной, если что-то поменять в переменной, меняется значение и в карте.
https://play.golang.org/p/4MZvJnAKOHz

А именно меняю значение структуры Phone

Ожидаю получить:
{dd 18 map[0:{623573}]} map[0:{eee}]

а получаю:
{dd 18 map[0:{eee}]} map[0:{eee}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map - это ссылочный тип данных. s и m[0] это два различных экземпляра Person, но поля Contacts у обоих ссылаются на один и тот же экземпляр map[int]Contact. Следовательно изменения вносимые через s.Contacts будут видны при обращении к m[0].Contacts.

Comment: А как сделать два различных экземпляра map[int]Contact?

Comment: Сразу после создания s, полю Contacts присвойте любую другую карту, например новую пустую:

    s.Contacts = make(map[int]Contact)

Теперь s.Contacts и m[0].Contacts будут ссылаться на различные карты.